# LIBGDX drawables on devices with different densities/resolutions

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new to LIBGDX game development, and I have faced my first problem. I've created 9.patch drawables (buttons) using texture packer. This drawables can be used on low density and also extra high density screens and quality is the same.

If I run my project with that drawable on desktop project the image shown is okay and perfect size. If I run project on low density android device, drawable becomes huge (almost half of the screen). And also If I run project on extra high density android device the button becomes really small.

So my question is, how to handle drawables in LIBGDX, so the ratio (screen:image size), stays the same no matter resolution/density..?

Comment: is it text button, image button or other?

Answer (score 0):

If your button is a text button. Change the font of your text.

If you are using image button, [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81304/libgdx-imagebutton-resizeing) might help you

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what you're drawing...If you are just drawing an image, I've found it easier to specify a float width and height in the last 2 parameters of the draw method. If you are using a camera with a fixed viewport size, you can simply use a fixed percentage of your camera viewport so it will always be the same dimensions and draw like this:

```
batch.draw(drawable,x,y,screenwidth * 0.5f,screenheight*0.5f);
```

However, if you are using buttons or some other widget inside of a table, you should specify the cell size and it should automatically be resized based on the size of the table cell. Something like:

```
myTable.add(myWidget).width(300).height(200);
```

Post up exactly what it is that you need to draw if you get a chance and it will be easier to figure out what needs to happen.

Comment: I'm currently making a menu. I've added a TextButton to a stage, and stage to a table and draw everything on the screen using "stage.draw()". Can you tell me more about fixed viewport size? I think that's the right approach but I don't know how to do this. Thank you :)